# Allow only certain commands in own environment

Tags: environments

I would like to define an environment `myenv` and allow only certain predefined commands to be executed betwwen `\begin{myenv}` and `\end{myenv}`.

For example I want text typed there to be ignored and also to give a list of commands which are allowed. Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you add an example of what you mean?

Comment: You can use `\nullfont` to ignore the text, but restricting other commands is harder as Matthew has said. It might help if we knew more about your application. For example, if `\fred` is allowed within `myenv`, do you want the user to be able to do `\newcommand{\xyzzy}{\fred\fred}` and use that?

Comment: Unfortunately `\nullfont` is inserting an undesired extra line. I would like to have something similar to the itemize environmant. There every line between `\begin{itemize}` and `\end{itemize}` has to begin with `\item`. Otherwise you get an error.

Answer (score 2):

For ignoring text, you could use `myenv` as a special type of `comment` environment (from the [package of the same name](http://ctan.org/pkg/comment)).  I don't think there's a way to only allow a certain number of macros, however.  You can disallow any macro by redefining it to give an error message.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\foo}{bar}

\specialcomment{myenv}{
    \newcommand{\nomacros}{%
        \GenericError{}{%
            Illegal macro%
        }{}{
        This macro is not allowed within the `myenv' environment
        }}%
    \let\foo\nomacros
    \let\bar\nomacros
}{}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{myenv}
\lipsum[1]
\foo\bar
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

The console will give:

> ```
> ! Illegal macro.
>
>
> Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
>  ...                                              
>
> l.2 \foo
>         \bar
> ? h
>  This macro is not allowed within the `myenv' environment 
> ? 
>
> ! Illegal macro.
>
>
> Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
>  ...                                              
>
> l.2 \foo\bar
>
> ? x
> No pages of output.
> ```