# Disallowing \textbf, \it, \sffamily, ... in argument of macro or environment

Tags: fonts, macros

I would like to have a command `\newcommand{\restricted}[1]{...}` which doesn't allow you to call it with something like

```
\restricted{calling me {\bf like} this \textit{is} not allowed}
```

i.e., the use of `\bf`, `\textbf`, `\tt`, and friends inside its argument should be forbidden.

Of course, I could, as suggested in [Allow only certain commands in own environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136260/allow-only-certain-commands-in-own-environment), redefined all these commands to throw an error inside my command, but this would be very unelegant.

As they are all font changing commands, I hope that there is some internal command that they all call, so that locally redefining this one command can give me the behavior I want.

Unfortunately I don't know how `\textbf` is implemented, couldn't find any documentation on its internal workings with google and `\show\textbf` isn't very informative.

To clarify: I don't just want to suppress the effect of these macros, but really disallow them. The background is that I am writing a documentclass, and as the content of `\title{}` should always look the same and is also used to automatically set pdf metadata, authors should not be able to say something like `\title{\textbf{I want my title bold}}`.

Comment: Presumably, your class will never be used for, say, book reviews and titles will not be permitted to include acronyms (at least, not acronyms set in small-caps)?

Comment: I don't expect anything like that. Titles might contain math, but that seems to be compatible with egreg's solution. At least `\restricted{$\mathrm{a}$}` works as expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no list of the font changing commands available, but you can redefine `\selectfont`, inside a group, to do nothing except issuing an error message.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\restricted}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\selectfont\cgogolin@error
  #1%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\cgogolin@error}{%
  \@latex@error{Font change not allowed}
    {You used a font changing command, which is\MessageBreak
     not permitted here}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\restricted{calling me {\bfseries like} this \textit{is} not allowed}

\end{document}
```

Here's the output on the terminal:

```
! LaTeX Error: Font change not allowed.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.19 ...series like} this \textit{is} not allowed}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution still allows font changes in math mode - which is actually what I want. Just thought it would be good to mention that.

Answer (score 2):

The following minimal example provides a selective font switch check by using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)'s `\patchcmd`. Each font switch is used to patch the argument of `\restricted`. If it is successful, an error is generated, otherwise nothing happens.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\restricted}[1]{%
  \def\restricted@arg{#1}%
  \renewcommand{\do}[1]{%
    \patchcmd{\restricted@arg}% <cmd>
      {##1}{##1}% <search><replace>
      {\cgogolin@error}{}% <success><failure>
  }
  \docsvlist{\bfseries,\textit}% Check for certain font uses... add more
  % <do stuff with #1>
}
\newcommand{\cgogolin@error}{%
  \@latex@error{Font change not allowed}
    {You used a font changing command, which is\MessageBreak
     not permitted here}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Calling me {\bfseries like} this \textit{is} allowed.

\restricted{Calling me {\bfseries like} this \textit{is} not allowed.}

\end{document}
```

This comes with the caveat that it tests for *explicit* use of any particular font switch. For example, `\bfseries` my be allowed if only checking for `\textbf`, say. Also, no expansion is performed on the argument, so hidden font switches won't be picked up (for example, if `\let\mybfseries\bfseries` is used).